# Per Color the max amount of bins used at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE #boxColor
(Color varchar(15)
,BoxId int
,AddedOn datetime2
,DeactivatedOn datetime2)

INSERT INTO #boxColor(Color, BoxId, AddedOn, DeactivatedOn)
VALUES 
('Black',1,'4/11/19 2:02 PM','12/31/99 12:00 AM'),
('Black',6,'4/12/19 11:16 AM','12/31/99 12:00 AM'),
('Black',7,'4/12/19 12:25 PM','12/31/99 12:00 AM'),
('blue',21,'4/12/19 1:14 PM','12/31/99 12:00 AM'),
('blue',31,'6/5/19 2:03 PM','12/31/99 12:00 AM'),
('yellow',32,'6/5/19 2:15 PM','8/8/19 4:53 PM'),
('orange',3,'6/7/19 9:01 AM','6/7/19 10:28 AM'),
('blue',34,'6/7/19 10:26 AM','6/7/19 11:20 AM'),
('orange',35,'6/7/19 10:28 AM','6/7/19 11:42 AM'),
('yellow',36,'6/7/19 11:20 AM','12/31/99 12:00 AM')
```

I am trying to get a list each color bin, and the max amount of that color that was ever in use at once

I can't seem to wrap my brain around this.

Let me know if I can clarify in any way.

Comment: *Let me know if I can clarify in any way.* Add expected results for your sample data.

Comment: By the way, you should really avoid ambiguous date formats, such as MDY and 2-digit years. See https://sqlblog.org/dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start by unpivoting the event dates (Added and Deactivated) into separate rows.

Then calculate a running sum of the difference in quantity between each event.

Then simply group it up and take the max.

```sql
SELECT
  bc.Color,
  PeakQty = MAX(bc.RunningSum)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      RunningSum = SUM(v.DiffQty) OVER (PARTITION BY bc.Color
                   ORDER BY v.EventDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM boxColor bc
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        (bc.AddedOn,        1),
        (bc.DeactivatedOn, -1)
    ) v(EventDate, DiffQty)
) bc
GROUP BY
  bc.Color;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b25b75caaec157d287bd7b43597bbe6e)

To elaborate on how this works:

- We take every `AddedOn` and `DeactivatedOn` date, and unpivot them into separate rows. For the former, we have a `DiffQty` of +1 and the latter -1.
- Think of the rows now as events: an addition and a removal.
- We then sort all those dates in order (partitoned by `Color`)....
- ... and we calculate a running sum of `DiffQty`, ordered by these unpivoted dates (and partitioned by `Color`). This means that each event either adds or removes 1 from the running sum.
- Then we can simply group it up by `Color`, and take the highest `RunningSum` value that we have.

Comment: Cool stuff! Thank you so much for taking the time! Would you be able to add the date time interval that the PeakQty was at, that way I can validate it?

Comment: If it helped you then feel free to upvote and/or accept (by clicking the check mark)

Comment: of course - would you be able to explain - how will this count the max number of boxes that were active at the same time? if there's any way to have the time interval that the most boxes were active- i would be able to query and validate. It's very cool you came that far- impressive

Comment: If you run the inner query by itself, you will see how it's doing it https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c92c50e8270ebd72b91b13986320ab8f. Yes you can get each period individually, it requires a couple more window functions https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f1700775a4a06ce616bf0e9506a51fa

Comment: One more thing - if you have time, i just don't understand why it works. It works, i validated it, and it's true, but why!? its just a running total and subtracting every time it's deactivated.. if you have a minute, can you explain the logic?

Comment: Have added more explanation, see edit

Comment: Thank you very much - this is the part I don't understand 

Color  AddedOn              DeactivatedOn             RunningSum    NextVal
Black 2019-06-05 14:15:49.377 2019-08-08 16:53:27.327 1 2019-06-07 09:01:07.873

Black 2019-06-07 09:01:07.873 2019-06-07 10:28:19.733 2 2019-06-07 10:26:55.337

Black 2019-06-07 10:26:55.337 2019-06-07 11:20:11.720 3 2019-06-07 10:28:19.733

Black 2019-06-07 09:01:07.873 2019-06-07 10:28:19.733 2 2019-06-07 10:28:19.733

when it reaches the last record, the last 3 are active at the same time, but it says 2

(need to paste into notepad for format)

Comment: That's more of a tie-break situation, and it's unclear why you would order one before the other.